# Using HttpServletRequest with ParallelStream in Java 8

Tags: java, spring-security, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have a simple application which will expose a RESTFul GET endpoint called `'getAllDeviceData'` which will simply return List of fetched data of all devices from the device table in a DB.

For each request I am authenticating the user by validating the `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()` method.
To speedup the process I have used parallelStream with lambda expressions.

In ParallelStream I am invoking another method called `'getDeviceData'` in which I am doing the authentication and fetch data from DB.

The problem is, when parallel stream process invokes `getDeviceDat`a method, I am getting a NullPointer exception and failed to complete the parallel steam.

The caues is, `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()` is null inside the method. But it actually exists in `'getAllDeviceData'` (where the lambda expression is).

This works without any issue if I replace `'parallelStream()'` with just `'stream()'` but in this case parallel nature is not there.

```
@Override
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "getAllDeviceData", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "*")
public List<List<Data>> getAllDeviceData(    
        @RequestParam(value = "recordLimit", required = false) final Integer recordLimit,         
        final HttpServletRequest request) {

    final List<Device> deviceList = deviceService.getAllDevices();   
    final List<List<Data>> dataList = deviceList.parallelStream().map(device -> getDeviceData(recordLimit, device.getDeviceId(), request)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return alerts;
}

private List<Data> getDeviceData(@RequestParam(value = "recordLimit", required = false) Integer recordLimit, String deviceId, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if(request.getUserPrincipal() == null){
        logger.info("User Principle Null - 1");
    }else {
        logger.info("User Principle Not Null - 1");
    }
    authService.doAuthenticate(request);

    // if authrnticated proceed with following...
    List<Data> deviceData = deviceService.getGetDeviceData(deviceId);
    return deviceData;
}
```

However, I have observed something.

Look at the following log (unnecessary parts have been ommitted) of above application.

In it, main threads (eg : `http-nio-7070-exec-2` etc. - which are main threads of thread pool of this application's server) are working fine because it prints out 'User Principle Not Null - 1' but, in broken down threads of parallel stream such as `ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2` etc.  `HTTPServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()` is becoming null.

```
2018-01-15 15:28:06,897 INFO [http-nio-7070-exec-2] User Principle Not Null - 1 
2018-01-15 15:28:06,897 INFO [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] User Principle Null - 1 
2018-01-15 15:28:06,906 INFO [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] User Principle Null - 1 

2018-01-15 15:28:06,955 INFO [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] User Principle Null - 1 
2018-01-15 15:28:06,955 INFO [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] User Principle Null - 1

2018-01-15 15:28:06,957 INFO [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] User Principle Null - 1 
2018-01-15 15:28:06,959 INFO [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] User Principle Null - 1
2018-01-15 15:28:07,064 INFO [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] User Principle Null - 1 

2018-01-15 15:28:07,076 INFO [http-nio-7070-exec-2] User Principle Not Null -1

2018-01-15 15:28:07,078 INFO [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] User Principle Null - 1
```

I am still new to lambda expressions and parallel stream.
Please help me understand what is the issue here.

Java Details:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the root cause is that Spring is injecting SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper instance into your method. This wrapper is calling the following lines when `equest.getUserPrincipal()` is called:

```
private Authentication getAuthentication() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

[SecurityContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) has different strategies. By default `MODE_THREADLOCAL` strategy is used. That's why you have user principle in main threads but don't have one in forkjoinpool threads.

`-Dspring.security.strategy=MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` VM option is a solution to your problem. [InheritableThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html) javadoc and InheritableThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy source code might bring additional value to the understanding.